# Display data and image from joined two tables in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, join

I want to display data and images from two tables joined, but the image doesn't display in view.
I have tables structure, Model, Controller, and View.

**Table Gallery** : id, title, created_at

**Table Gallery_images** : id, id_gallery, file_name, uploaded_at

**MyModel**

```
    class Mymodel extends CI_Model {
    public function getData()
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('gallery');

        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
    public function getImages()
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('gallery');
        $this->db->join('gallery_images', 'gallery_images.id_gallery=gallery.id');

        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

**MyController**

```
class Mycontroller extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model("mymodel");
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data = $this->mymodel->getData();
        $images = $this->mymodel->getImages();
        $this->load->view('gallery/index', compact('data', 'images'));
    }
}
```

**MyView**

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
         <div id="filter-container">
            <button class="fiter-button active" onclick="filterSelection('all')">All Photo</button>
            <?php foreach($data as $data) { ?>
               <button class="fiter-button" onclick="filterSelection('<?php echo $data->id ?>')"><?php echo $data->title ?></button>
            <?php } ?>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

// No Images Displayed
<div class="row">
   <?php foreach($images as $images) { ?>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 filterDiv <?php echo $images->id ?>">
         <img src="<?php echo base_url('myImages/'.$images->file_name) ?>" alt="" class="photo-card mb-2 myImg">
      </div>
   <?php } ?>
</div>
```

How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

> You are using same variables try to change second variable like this

```
    <div class="row">
   <?php foreach($images as $images) { ?>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 filterDiv <?php echo $images->id ?>">
         <img src="<?php echo base_url('myImages/'.$images->file_name) ?>" alt="" class="photo-card mb-2 myImg">
      </div>
   <?php } ?>
</div>
```

> into

```
    <div class="row">
   <?php foreach($images as $image) { ?>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 filterDiv <?php echo $image->id ?>">
         <img src="<?php echo base_url('myImages/'.$image->file_name) ?>" alt="" class="photo-card mb-2 myImg">
      </div>
   <?php } ?>
</div>
```